# How can i add domain url to the url of uploaded files when selected on ckfinder

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ckeditor, ckfinder

I'm setting up `ckfinder` on CKEditor 4. When I select an image with "browse server" button, the URL of image is: `/ckfinder/userfiles/images/image.png`.

But it should be full URL like: `http://example.com/ckfinder/userfiles/images/image.png`.

[image]

My `ckeditor/config.js` file:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'content_en', {
    filebrowserBrowseUrl: 
    './assets/app/js/ckfinder/ckfinder.html',
filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: 
    './assets/app/js/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Images',
filebrowserUploadUrl: 
    './assets/app/js/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files',
filebrowserImageUploadUrl: 
    './assets/app/js/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Images'
});
```

My `config.php` file in `ckfinder`:

```
$config['backends'][] = array(
    'name'         => 'default',
    'adapter'      => 'local',
    'baseUrl'      => '/ckfinder/userfiles/',
//  'root'         => '', // Can be used to explicitly set the  CKFinder user files directory.
    'chmodFiles'   => 0777,
    'chmodFolders' => 0755,
    'filesystemEncoding' => 'UTF-8',
);
```

Comment: Try `$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . baseUrl`

Comment: it creates a new folder like 'example.com/ckfinder/userfiles/' but i want to show images with full url

Comment: omg i added http:// and solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add full path in `backend` configuration for `baseUrl` property.

Instead of:

```
'baseUrl'      => '/ckfinder/userfiles/',
```

Please use :

```
'baseUrl'      => 'http://example.com//ckfinder/userfiles/',
```